# Write sf object failed because of the CPL_write_ogr error

Tags: r, r-sf

I want to export my sf object which was made by unioning two countries' sf. I don't know why the error occurs when I write it out with `st_write`. Even if the error message shows, it does have files occur in assgined destination, but I can't read it in R. Please give me some suggestions. Thank you in advance.

My code:

```
library(sf)
library(tmap)
Montenegro <- st_read("z:\\NTU\\master research\\GIS data\\World_Countres_WGS84\\Supplementary_Countries\\Montenegro\\MNE_adm0.shp")
Serbia <- st_read("z:\\NTU\\master research\\GIS data\\World_Countres_WGS84\\Supplementary_Countries\\Serbia\\SRB_adm0.shp")
Serbia.Montenegro <- st_union(Montenegro, Serbia)
st_write(Serbia.Montenegro, "z:\\NTU\\master research\\GIS data\\World_Countres_WGS84\\Supplementary_Countries\\Serbia and Montenegro\\SerAndMon.shp")
```

Error message:

```
Error in CPL_write_ogr(obj, dsn, layer, driver, as.character(dataset_options),  : 
  Write error
In addition: There were 12 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
```

Read it back to R:

```
test <- st_read("z:\\NTU\\master research\\GIS data\\World_Countres_WGS84\\Supplementary_Countries\\Serbia and Montenegro\\SerAndMon.shp")
qtm(test)
```

Error message:

```
Error: no layer elements defined after tm_shape
```

Files can be download here:

Montenegro shapefile: https://geodata.mit.edu/catalog/stanford-hz193rg6075

Serbia shapefile: https://geodata.mit.edu/catalog/stanford-nw199gc0423

Comment: The problem might be related to the field names. Are you willing to consider different file formats than shapefile for saving the data?

Answer (score 0):

As @agila mentioned, the issue is something funny in at least one of the fields. After running `st_union` the file has 68 fields, some of which hold special characters from other languages. Best guess is it has something to do with encoding?

As a test, if we subset to only having three fields before writing the shapefile, it seems to work fine.

```r
# download and unzip data
test_dir <- tempdir()

urls <- c('https://stacks.stanford.edu/file/druid:hz193rg6075/data.zip',
          'https://stacks.stanford.edu/file/druid:nw199gc0423/data.zip')

download_and_extract <- function(url, ex_dir){
  temp_file <- tempfile()
  download.file(url, temp_file)
  unzip(temp_file, exdir = ex_dir)
}


invisible(lapply(urls, download_and_extract, ex_dir = test_dir))

# run st_union on the two shapefiles
serb_mon <- list.files(test_dir, '.shp$', full.names = TRUE)
serb_mon <- lapply(serb_mon, sf::read_sf)
serb_mon <- do.call(sf::st_union, serb_mon)
#> although coordinates are longitude/latitude, st_union assumes that they are planar
#> Warning: attribute variables are assumed to be spatially constant throughout all
#> geometries


# write the new unioned layer to an ESRI shapefile 
# note the subset to only 3 columns/fields
sf::st_write(serb_mon[,1:3], file.path(test_dir, 'serb_mon.shp'))
#> Writing layer `serb_mon' to data source `C:\Users\colinn\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp4CJyUu/serb_mon.shp' using driver `ESRI Shapefile'
#> Writing 1 features with 3 fields and geometry type Multi Polygon.


# test out reading and plotting the new shapefile
exported_shp <- sf::st_read(file.path(test_dir, 'serb_mon.shp'))
#> Reading layer `serb_mon' from data source `C:\Users\colinn\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp4CJyUu\serb_mon.shp' using driver `ESRI Shapefile'
#> Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 3 fields
#> Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 18.45892 ymin: 41.84792 xmax: 22.97898 ymax: 46.1894
#> Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84

plot(exported_shp)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-07-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>